# Force string type when indexing unknown field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nosql

I'm trying to index documents where I do not know a part of the document which I declare it as object. What I want to achieve is to "tell" to elasticsearch to index any field I give within this object as string, in other words any integer, long, **date** field to be mapped and stored as of type string, e.g.

lets assume we have the following document to index

```
{
  "foo":"bar",
  "custom_object":{
    "a_name":"jim",
    "a_date":"2016-3-31"
  }
}
```

I do **NOT** know a priori what are the name of my fields inside *custom_object*, the mapping of this document *log* is the following:

```
"mappings": {
       'log': {
          'properties': {
              'foo': {
                  'type': 'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
              },
              'custom_object': {
                  'type': 'object'
              }
       }
 }
```

How can I tell, whatever I give to the document inside custom_object to be mapped as string? and this mostly has to do with **date** values, were I'm facing the issue. I do not want to ignore it with *dynamic=false* or *enabled =false* (taken from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-object-type.html)). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) to say that all fields within the name `custom_object` has to be mapped as `string`

When defining mapping, you can set it as follows

```
     "dynamic_templates":[
        {
           "custom_object_template":{
              "path_match":"custom_object.*",
              "mapping":{
                 "type": "string"
              }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> When Elasticsearch encounters a new string field, it checks to see if
>   the string contains a recognizable date, like 2014-01-01. If it looks
>   like a date, the field is added as type date. Otherwise, it is added
>   as type string.

You can customize [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html) in elasticsearch to suit your needs.

Date detection can be turned off by setting `date_detection` to `false` on the root object:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "date_detection": false
        }
    }
}
```

With this mapping in place, a `string` will always be a `string`. If you need a `date` field, you have to add it manually.